# creating names using backticks vs using single and double quotes in R

Tags: r

"You can also create non-syntactic bindings using single or double quotes (e.g. "_abc" <- 1) instead of backticks, **but you shouldn’t, because you’ll have to use a different syntax to retrieve the values**. The ability to use strings on the left hand side of the assignment arrow is an historical artefact, used before R supported backticks."

The quote above is from Hadley Wickham's book.

Can you give any example of the bolded?
In my experience, I find no difference in retrieving names created with backticks or quotes.

Comment: I suspect it's historical or a typo.  It probably meant to say that historically, you needed a different syntax to retrieve non-regular variables before backticks.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the intended difference is that if you instantiate with double-quotes, you can't access the variable in that fashion.

```r
"mu" <- 2
"mu"
# [1] "mu"
mu
# [1] 2
```

Whereas if you create it with backticks, you can still access it with backticks:

```r
`mu` <- 2
`mu`
# [1] 2
```

There are of course special ways (`get("mu")`), but that's different.